# How to perform custom decimal conversion in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Hi I am new to Power BI and I have a simple problem

I have a table like this

| Number |
| --- |
| 3.4 |
| 10.5 |
| 12.4 |

I want to create a custom column that would take number before decimal place and multiply it with another number(eg. 10) and then add the digit behind the decimal for example 3.4 becomes (3 X 10)+4 = 34. So the custom column becomes like this

| Number | Custom |
| --- | --- |
| 3.4 | 34 |
| 10.5 | 105 |
| 12.4 | 124 |
| 7 | 70 |

Also I understand I can split the actual column into 2 columns using split on delimiter and then make a 3rd calculated column but for learning purpose I want to create it as a custom column (if it is allowed/possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Number.IntegerDivide version:**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
MultiplyBy=10,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Number.IntegerDivide([Number],1)*MultiplyBy+10*([Number]-Number.IntegerDivide([Number],1)))
in #"Added Custom"
```

Number.IntegerDivide([Number],1) is the integer part we multiply by the variable **MultiplyBy**

[Number]-Number.IntegerDivide([Number],1) is the decimal part, we multiply by 10 before adding

**Text.Split version:**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
MultiplyBy=10,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Number.From(Text.Split(Text.From([Number]),"."){0})*MultiplyBy +  Number.From(try Text.Split(Text.From([Number]),"."){1} otherwise 0))
in #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: This works. I wonder how do people get so good at something :P

Comment: Spend a few thousand hours on it :)